# Send email with email attchments

Tags: c#, smtp, .net-4.5

I am attempting to send an email that has attachments. 
The exception: "Failure sending email"
The inner exception: "Cannot access a closed stream"

```
MailMessage mm1 = new MailMessage();
mm1.IsBodyHtml = true;
mm1.Body = "Body for person to approve";
mm1.Subject = "Home Owner's Insurance Policy";
mm1.From = new MailAddress("insurance@email.com", "ReplyName");
mm1.ReplyTo = new MailAddress("insurance@email.com");
mm1.To.Add("ross.kriel@email.co.za");

foreach (NewBusinessData item in lData)
{

    MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
    mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mm.Body = HTMLBody;
    mm.Subject = "Home Owner's Insurance Policy";
    mm.From = new MailAddress("insurance@email.com","ReplyName");
    mm.ReplyTo = new MailAddress("insurance@email.com");

   byte[] thisAttachment;
   thisAttachment = Common.Attach(Settings.Default.NewBusinessCSFDataFileWriterPath + item.PolicyNumber + "_" + item.MortgageLoanAccountNumber + ".pdf");

    Stream ClientPDF = new MemoryStream(thisAttachment);

    Attachment attStaticPDF = new Attachment(StaticPDF, "Home Owner's Insurance Policy.pdf");
    Attachment attClientPDF = new Attachment(ClientPDF, item.PolicyNumber + ".pdf");
    mm.Attachments.Add(attStaticPDF);
    mm.Attachments.Add(attClientPDF);

    Assembly assembly = typeof(SmtpClient).Assembly;
    Type mailWriterType = assembly.GetType("System.Net.Mail.MailWriter");
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
         ConstructorInfo mailWriterContructor = mailWriterType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { typeof(Stream) }, null);
         object mailWriter = mailWriterContructor.Invoke(new object[] { stream });
         MethodInfo sendMethod = typeof(MailMessage).GetMethod("Send", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
         sendMethod.Invoke(mm, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { mailWriter, true, true }, null);

         Attachment emailAtt = new Attachment(stream, "Home Owner's Insurance Policy.msg");

         mm1.Attachments.Add(emailAtt);                                                    
     }                                                                                                                                                                    
 }
 SmtpClient smtp1 = new SmtpClient();
 smtp1.Host = "HostIP";
 smtp1.Port = 25;
 try
 {
     smtp1.Send(mm1);
 }
 catch (Exception exd)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(exd.ToString());
 }
```

Comment: Why are you using reflection to instantiate and invoke methods? Just for the fun of it or am i missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So at the end of the day it was the Transfer Encoding that caused the problem. Specifying it as Eight bit and ensuring the attachment also had the right media type solved the problem.

```
MailMessage mm1 = new MailMessage();
mm1.IsBodyHtml = true;
mm1.Body = ReportMsgBody;
mm1.Subject = "Home Owner's Insurance Policy Proofs: " + lData.Select(x => x.FileName).First();
mm1.From = new MailAddress("insurance@email.com", "FromName");
mm1.ReplyTo = new MailAddress("insurance@email.com");
mm1.To.Add(receiver.EmailAddress);

foreach (NewBusinessData item in lData)
{
    MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
    mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mm.Body = HTMLBody;
    mm.Subject = "Home Owner's Insurance Policy";
    mm.From = new MailAddress("insurance@email.com", "FromName");
    mm.ReplyTo = new MailAddress("insurance@email.com");
    mm.To.Add(item.EmailAddress);

    byte[] thisAttachment;
    thisAttachment = Common.Attach(Settings.Default.FileWriterPath + item.PolicyNumber + "_" + item.MortgageLoanAccountNumber + ".pdf");
    Stream ClientPDF = new MemoryStream(thisAttachment);
    Attachment attClientPDF = new Attachment(ClientPDF, item.Pr + ".pdf", "application/pdf");
    mm.Attachments.Add(attClientPDF);

    byte[] thisAttachment2;
    thisAttachment2 = Common.Attach(Settings.Default.StaticAttatchmentPath + "Home Owner's Insurance Policy.pdf");
    Stream StaticPDF = new MemoryStream(thisAttachment2);
    Attachment attStaticPDF = new Attachment(StaticPDF, "Home Owner's Insurance Policy.pdf", "application/pdf");
    mm.Attachments.Add(attStaticPDF);

    Assembly assembly = typeof(SmtpClient).Assembly;
    Type mailWriterType = assembly.GetType("System.Net.Mail.MailWriter");
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

    ConstructorInfo mailWriterContructor = mailWriterType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { typeof(Stream) }, null);
    object mailWriter = mailWriterContructor.Invoke(new object[] { stream });
    MethodInfo sendMethod = typeof(MailMessage).GetMethod("Send", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    sendMethod.Invoke(mm, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { mailWriter, true, true }, null);

    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    Attachment emailAtt = new Attachment(stream, "Home Owner's Insurance Policy", "message/rfc822");
    emailAtt.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.EightBit;
    mm1.Attachments.Add(emailAtt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply Wrap the using Clause around the whole thing. Your stream gets out of scope once the batch-Code inside using clause has been executed.

Try this:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
         ConstructorInfo mailWriterContructor = mailWriterType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { typeof(Stream) }, null);
         object mailWriter = mailWriterContructor.Invoke(new object[] { stream });
         MethodInfo sendMethod = typeof(MailMessage).GetMethod("Send", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
         sendMethod.Invoke(mm, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { mailWriter, true, true }, null);

         Attachment emailAtt = new Attachment(stream, "Home Owner's Insurance Policy.msg");

         mm1.Attachments.Add(emailAtt);                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 SmtpClient smtp1 = new SmtpClient();
 smtp1.Host = "HostIP";
 smtp1.Port = 25;
 try
     smtp1.Send(mm1);
} // Ending using Clause
```

---

Or infact dont use the Using clause here, as there is no need for it here.

Answer (score 0):

Stream gets closed once you get out of "using" scope. Instead don't do using but close stream after you send

```
 try
 {
   smtp1.Send(mm1);
   stream.Close();
 }
 catch (Exception exd)
 {
   Console.WriteLine(exd.ToString());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're losing the MemoryStream because of the using. You don't have to use the using here.

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
```

use:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()
```

The using isn't needed because there is no unmanaged handles bound to the memoryStream (like FileStream)

If you still want to use the using/dispose method. You can add them to a list and cleanup at the end.